# $scope elements not visible outside of directive (using $scope:false)

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a simple directive which uses the parent scope. However I cannot access the scope of the directive. What am I doing wrong?

```
<p>myFrm2.$name: {{myFrm2.$name}}</p>

<pane>
  <form name="myFrm2" id="myFrm2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="fld2">
  </form>
</pane>
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/AIUK2tBiiVs21so2k5JR?p=preview

This is the directive:

```
.directive('pane', function() {
        return {
          restrict: 'E',
          transclude: true,
          scope: false,
          template: '<div style="border: 1px solid black;">' +
            '<div style="background-color: gray; color:white">Test Directive</div>' +
            '<ng-transclude></ng-transclude>' +
            '</div>'
        };
      })
```

As I am setting $scope:false in my directive, I would suppose that the scope is shared between the directive and its parent scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue disappears when you use object models or controllerAs alias.

Example with object

in controller

```
  $scope.forms ={};
```

In view

```
<p>myFrm2.$name: {{forms.myFrm2.$name}}</p>

<pane>
  <form name="forms.myFrm2" id="myFrm2">
    <input type="text" ng-model="fld2">
  </form>
</pane>
```

Note that you should always use object in `ng-model` also

<kbd>**[DEMO](https://plnkr.co/edit/249tFLxJDslkyqV0bNkL?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Thank you. I will try it with controllerAs, too.

Comment: Just using controllerAs does not help me - am I missing something? https://plnkr.co/edit/Kpc13ckgWnJB2UTfm3BB?p=preview

Comment: Not prefixing all the variables as properties of alias....including the form name  https://plnkr.co/edit/I0OWmwJFZbGNg631pWyw?p=preview